# Android TImer: Add a timer

Tags: android, timer, reset

I've been experimenting with Eclipse a bit...
and I almost finished a timer :)
Although, I can't get the Reset button working...

**Res/Layout/main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/timerVal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:text="@string/startButtonLabel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:text="@string/pauseButtonLabel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetButton"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/timerValue"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
            android:text="@string/resetButtonLabel" />

</RelativeLayout>
[/code]

[B]res/values/strings.xml[/B]
[code]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Timer</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="timerVal">00:00:00</string>
    <string name="pauseButtonLabel">Pause</string>
    <string name="startButtonLabel">Start</string>
    <string name="resetButtonLabel">Reset</string>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.MertensMobile.Timer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;

    private TextView timerValue;

    private long startTime = 0L;

    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            }
        });

       resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);

        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            }
        });

    }
    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
        public void Reset() {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();

            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    };

}
```

I'm very close, (at least I think I am) :P

I got it working on my cellphone, just the reset isn't working yet :o

Comment: what exactly is not working? What do You want to do with this button? I miss Your @Override annotations insde Your onClickListeners...

Comment: Well I seek a working reset-button. It has a working Start and Pause button, but I want my reset-button to actually bring the counter back to 00:00:00

Comment: @Wince Ty for your respond, but it only gives me errors :/

Comment: I really need a good and easy answer, I've been trying a thousand things and I only get errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this to reset the timer.

```
TimerValue.cancel();

        TextView digital_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digital_display);
        digital_display.setText("00:00.0");
```

Comment: Well you see my code. Where do I put it?
Because every try so far got me errors only.                         ty for your help :)

Comment: sorry for late answer . But you need to give information about thee errors u get so we can help you . This code piece is so you can reset the timer u put it in the reset button ( which i'm sure you tried).

Comment: from the ErrorLog or from the LogCat ? (cuzz the LogCat is quite a long one)          -  Pressing the 'Reset' in the emulator doesn't give me an error, I just don't get any effect, it just does quite the same as the Start button, it continues the counting. (ATM the ErrorLog isn't working, trying to fix that as well)

Comment: Although when I open my app in the Emulator, the Logcat gives me this: http://i57.tinypic.com/azc3n4.png

Comment: sorry but work network doesn't let me see your link :) would appreciate if u can copy paste and the logcat error usually gives a lot but the there should be a start point commonly exceptions.